# WP core emails translated

Tags: localization

Is there a way to send out translated WP core emails? So with core I mean the emails like "Lost password", "New registration" etc.

Currently my site uses WPML that does a good job however can't translate those emails. 
I have 3 languages on my site and would like to send emails based on the selected language in the site. So when people viewing the spanish version of the site he/she should recieve mails in Spanish. Same for other languages.

I have absolutely no idea where to start. I even can't find something in Google. 
Is it that difficult to make?

Any advice more then welcome

Comment: If you [look at wp-login](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/2152a6a1ea3db59fcc626fe8129d6fc175e0df66/wp-login.php#L327) you can see that these are assembled from separate translatable strings "Someone has requested a password reset for the following account:", "To reset your password, visit the following address:" - if you can find those in WPML you can translate them, or if not that's probably worth asking their support about it. Alternatively you can replace the entire message body with the retrieve_password_message filter if you write (or find) a small plugin instead.